# how to call Javascript method from MVC4 link (error JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript code which should be started after clicking on link on view page, but the error is displayed. What is wrong?
Error is: '
0x800a01bd - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action'

Javascript code:

```
var MenuController = function () {    
};

MenuController.prototype.Logout = function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Account/Logout',
        success: function (response) {
            alert('log out');
            window.close();
        }
    });

};
```

HTML code:

```
<a onclick="new MenuController.Logout();" alt="Log out">Log out</a>
                            </li>
...
 <script src="/js/Controller/MenuController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: In what line does this error occur?

Comment: 1) I added line with script element to example, 2) error is in line with code `new MenuController.Logout()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the brackets to construct the MenuController.  `new MenuController.Logout();` should become `new MenuController().Logout();`

Answer (score 1):

You need to construct your `MenuController` object. At the moment you are calling `Logout` like a static function (not a prototype method).

```
new MenuController.Logout()
```

Is generally wrong.

either:

```
var MenuController = function () {    
};

MenuController.prototype.Logout = function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Account/Logout',
        success: function (response) {
            alert('log out');
            window.close();
        }
    });

};
```

Invoke with:

```
new MenuController().Logout();
```

or hold it as a static function:

```
var MenuController = {
  Logout: function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/Account/Logout',
        success: function (response) {
            alert('log out');
            window.close();
        }
    });
  }
};
```

Invoke with:

```
MenuController.Logout();
```

I hope this helps,

Rhys